# Return true or false if node is present in binary tree. Please explain its dry run

Tags: java, function, recursion

Sample tree:

```
                       8
            3                   10
       1          6         -1       14
     -1 -1    4       7           13    -1
            -1 -1   -1 -1       -1 -1
```

Binary tree and -1 if you don't want to add further node
Sample element to be searched: 7

Output:
true

```
public static boolean isNodePresent(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root,int x){
        if(root==null)
            return false;
        
        boolean ans=false;
        
        if(root.data==x)
            return true;
        
        ans=isNodePresent(root.left,x);
                if(ans)
                return ans;
        ans=isNodePresent(root.right,x);
        return ans;

    }
```

I want to know how the recursion is working with my sample input.
When the recursion is starting the 8 is checked if it is element or not then according to this solution 3 will be the next to checked if it is equal to element or not then 1 ,4 ,13. But I dont understand how the second recursive call is working.

Comment: What is the question / problem in here?

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. If you have a question with your code, we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: Are you asking for a "dry run" (assuming that is a step by step description of what happens) along with an explanation of each step? That lacks focus on the specific part of that which you do not understand. Please show what you have after trying yourself and point out the part which you doubt. Since this seems very much to be homework  related please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Well with that sample input, the code will insert 8,3,10,1,6 into the tree, stop inserting at the first -1, look for the 14 inside the existing tree, output "false" and then be surprised by the following -1. I hence believe that the shown sample input is inconistent and does not match the shown output. I suspect that the many "-1"s indicate that you have a formatting issue with showing the input, possibly it is a tree representation, the white space of which did not make it through copy-pasting. Please double check. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Yunnosch -1 is for stating that no further node is inserted here and tree is like 8:L:3,R:10
3:L:1,R:6
10:L:-1,R:14
1:L:-1,R:-1
6:L:4,R:7
14:L:13,R:-1
4:L:-1,R:-1
7:L:-1,R:-1
13:L:-1,R:-1
L is for left and R is for right

Comment: I checked my guess and found that your "sample input" is a very plausible mal-formatted tree representatin. NOT a sample input. Please edit to avoid confusion by that mislabeling.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for proper formatting

Comment: "...then 1 ,4 ,13". No, you missed the 6.

Comment: Good work editing your own thoughts in. That allows to answer....

Comment: Can you please explain the recursion now

Answer (score 0):

Your thoughts are correct until "then 1".

But then:

- return from left recursion, back at node "3"
- enter right recursion, looking at node "6"
- wrong
- enter left recursion, looking at node "4"
- wrong
- return from left recursion, back at node "6"
- enter right recursion, looking at node "7"
- match!
- return to "6"
- return to "3"
- return to "8"
- return result

I left out all non-nodes (null, "-1"), which are entered and return from with "false".

Comment: Please remove the second question again. Only one question per post and please avoid "moving target questions".